# Find X and Y such that AX=B and YA=B

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am a little confused by this question the matrix A is given as,
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1\\
5&3
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
Matrix B 
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
2&4\\
1&3
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

I found AX=B, but YA=B wouldn't that give me the same answer ? I dont understand why would i get a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $X\neq Y$ where $AX=B$ and $YA=B$ since matrix multiplcation is **not** commutative. Since $\det A$ and $\det B$ are not zero you can compute $X$ and $Y$ by
$$ X= A^{-1} B \qquad \text{and} \qquad Y= BA^{-1}.$$
You will see that $ A^{-1} B\neq BA^{-1}$ what shows $X\neq Y$.

Comment: @Julian answered my question correctly as well but since you have the exact answer ill select this , yea in my mind I was thinking of matrix being commutative.

Comment: You can accept whatever you like :) We just want to help you and make things clear!

Answer (score 2):

It's not about getting a different matrix $B$, but about the concept that the multiplication of matrices is not commutative, so it is not necessarily $AX = XA$. You are obligated to find a different matrix $Y$ such that $AX = YA$, but that doesn't mean that $X = Y$. Since you already solved $AX = B$, try to calculate $XA$, and you should find that $AX \neq XA$.

This tells you that, in order to solve the excercise, you need to define $Y$ differently.